# "UnicodeDecodeError" when trying to load a model with Tensorflow 2.5.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

Reutilizing code I found [online](https://github.com/yulinliu101/DeepTP), I am building a neural network with tensorflow 2.5.0 .
When trying to load the saved model with the
`tf.train.Saver` function, I get the following error:

```
; Input/output error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adame\Documents\DeepTPmaster\src\Run_RNN_model_Lite.py", line 826, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adame\Documents\DeepTPmaster\src\Run_RNN_model_Lite.py", line 824, in main
    tf_train.run_model(train_from_model = False,
  File "C:\Users\adame\Documents\DeepTPmaster\src\Run_RNN_model_Lite.py", line 177, in run_model
    self.saver.restore(self.sess, self.restored_model_path)
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1303, in restore
    sess.run(self.saver_def.restore_op_name,
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 967, in run
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1190, in _run
    results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1368, in _do_run
    return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1375, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1359, in _run_fn
    return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
  File "C:\Users\adame\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1451, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 288: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: first you should check what encoding has char with code `0xe8` - maybe data are in `latin1`, `cp1250` or other encoding.

Comment: if I run `b'\xe8'.decode('utf-8') ` then I get error but for `b'\xe8'.decode('latin1')` it gives `è` and for `b'\xe8'.decode('cp1250')` gives `č` - so your data are not in `utf-8`